# Escape Special Characters in Python 3.x

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here is my Sample Code

```
import re
string = "->A.T.A<-BlackDrago"
escaped = re.escape(string)
print(escaped)
```

**Output:**
`\->A\.T\.A<\-BlackDrago`

**Expected Output:**
`\-\>A\.T\.A\<\-BlackDrago`

Comment: *Why* did you expect this particular output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of Python 3.7 re.escape() was changed to escape only characters which are meaningful to regex operations(that's way < and > are not escaped).

You can use the regex module as alternative:

```
pip install regex
```

Change your code to:

```
import regex
string = "->A.T.A<-BlackDrago"
escaped = regex.escape(string,special_only=False)
print(escaped)
```

```
>>> print(escaped)
\-\>A\.T\.A\<\-BlackDrago
```

Answer (score 3):

You're asking why some characters were not escaped. The characters that were not escaped, but are escaped in your 'expected output' are '>' and '<'.

According [to the documentation of re.escape](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.escape):

Changed in version 3.7: Only characters that can have special meaning in a regular expression are escaped. As a result, ... '<', '=', '>', ... are no longer escaped.